# How can WGS be done on a bone marrow transplant recipient?

Tags: dna

Most of the testing companies use a saliva sample that contains white blood cells for doing Whole Genome Sequencing (WGS) of your DNA.  White blood cells are created by your bone marrow, so if you get a bone marrow transplant, then your white blood cells now have the DNA of your donor.

Is there another source of DNA that is not corrupted by the bone marrow donor and if so, what WGS testing companies have a way for providing a sample of that source?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this adequately covers your question or not:

Because your cheek swap may contain both epithelial as well as white blood cells, 23&me says they cannot be assured that your specimen will not be confounded by the white blood cells contributed by a bone marrow transplant.
 See [from 23&me](https://customercare.23andme.com/hc/en-us/articles/202907990-I-received-a-bone-marrow-transplant-can-I-use-the-23andMe-Personal-Genetic-Service-)

**Their statement suggests that if a cheek swab contains ONLY epithelial cells that the analysis could work ok.**

Another interesting article: [DNA replacement](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/12/07/us/dna-bone-marrow-transplant-crime-lab.html)

** But caution is suggested even when using only epithelials as outlined here: [forensic failures](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3578715/)